# How to read NSArray value in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)[[myClass getFinalPath]count]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run UI Updates
            });
        });
```

I am trying to read an NSArray value, if I read NSArray value outside the `dispatch_async` I am able to read it but when it's inside it's returning zero, I am very new to `dispatch_async` and I'm having problem understanding the tutorials and reference from Apple I have read, please if anybody could help. my `[myClass getFinalPath]` returns an NSArray filled with certain amount of value btw.

Comment: How did you implement `getFinalPath` ?

Comment: I just returned the array

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch_async` captures the values of the variables in the current scope and executes the code inside the block "later" asynchronously. This code

```
__block NSInteger i = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
  i = 10;
  NSLog(@"inside %ld", i);        
});
NSLog(@"outside %ld", i);
```

logs always first `outside 0`, then `inside 10`

You have to read and process the array inside the dispatch block

Answer (score 0):

pass array as parameter to function

```
 (void)passArrayToDispatchSync:(NSArray *)someArray
 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
 NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)[someArray count]);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run UI Updates
            });
        });
 }
```